# CC .Net is stuck Getting source

Tags: cruisecontrol

I'm running CruiseControl.NET Version : 1.6.7981.1 on Window Server.
I have 4 project set up. Only one (let's call it A) checks source control automatically every 4000 seconds. The others (B,C,D) are manual only.

Right now A is just sitting there Getting source. I checked the code directory and it was out of date. So I updated the code directory. Attempted to stopped the cc service, it would not stop. Force killed the cc service.  Cleaned out the artifacts, and all the other old files. Started the cc service. Now I'm in the same boat. It still just shows Getting source.

A is in it's own queue. B, C, and D all build on command without issue.

Anyone have an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't getting stuck... I changed the wrong value. Instead of changing:

```
<intervalTrigger name="Trunk SVN Commit" seconds="60" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
```

to

```
<intervalTrigger name="Trunk SVN Commit" seconds="4000" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
```

I had changed:

```
<modificationDelaySeconds>4000</modificationDelaySeconds>
```

So cc.net was working just like it's should. It was checking for a change then waiting 4000 seconds to actually update.